# Rearranging equation for easier computability

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

Suppose I have the function 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^4} - \sqrt{1-x^3}$$

I want to compute it when $x$ is very small, but this introduces lots of big errors because both terms in the function are of similar magnitude.

So I was thinking I could rearrange it so that this subtraction of terms of similar magnitude for small $x$ goes away... but how could it be changed?

---

My only thinking was that I could use the Taylor Series expansion of $f$ at $0$.... but this is obviously a lot worse than if I just had another form for the general function that was easily computable for small values of $x$.

I tried doing log/exponent tricks and refactoring so that I get an addition or something, but have not been successful.

Comment: I would use the Taylor expansions and combine them, at very small values of x the errors relating to it as an approximation will be very small

Comment: I do not really understand how $\dfrac{x^3+x^4}2$ (the Taylor expansion) is worse than the accepted solution ? It differs only from an $O(x^6)$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write (rationalising the denominator)
$$f(x)=\frac{x^4+x^3}{\sqrt{1+x^4}+\sqrt{1-x^3}}.$$